# How to deep copy a complex object with EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to copy a complex object with EmberJS. This object contains arrays, other objects, data values, strings and other values. I see the Copy method is deprecated and there is an addon called ember-copy to replace it.

I tried to use the ember-copy addon but when I set the second argument to true (indicating that I want a deep copy) it says I cannot copy an object that does not implement Ember.Copyable. I transformed this object to an EmberObject, passing the Copyable mixing, but even with that it says I need to implement a Copy method. I do not understand why I would need the ember-copy addon if I need to implement it manually.

I believe cloning an object should be something a framework must be capable of doing. Every framework I used provided a way to do it with no effort, but it seems to be a hard thing to do with Ember.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` is the way to go, I think, according to [this comment](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/315#issuecomment-375321201) in the official repo

Comment: No, the simple JSON string method is often no use.

Comment: I understand the issue, one possible way is to take advantage of ES6 Proxy. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy I will provide  a sample code later.

Comment: @KenOKABE - "often", but really depends on the original complex object. The question states the object contains "arrays, other objects, data values, strings and other values" - which is vague ... what are these "other objects", are they `Object`s? and `other values` ... what other values? are there any circular references? - the downside of JSON methods is `Prototype will be lost. Cloned object will be created from Object class.` and `Will throw error in circular objects.` - according to http://voidcanvas.com/clone-an-object-in-vanilla-js-in-depth/

Comment: @JaromandaX Deep copy is real  issue with headache, and many say, oh it's easy, just use "Json Stringfy/Parse". The fact is not that easy. Does Undercore/Lo-dash library use Json Stringly for DeepCopy? Absolutely not. There's a reason. One clean way to avoid the mess is to use ES6 Proxy, it might not be a silver bullet, but in many cases, this method does what we want. I've posted a  sample code as an answer.

Comment: I agree. But with vague description of the object it's possible json methods are enough

Comment: Depending on your use case you might want to use an [ember-changeset](https://github.com/poteto/ember-changeset) or an [ember-buffer-proxy](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-buffered-proxy). They are not creating a copy of object like deprecated copy method of Ember does, but providing a proxy that buffers changes until they are applied to your object.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use spread operator (ES6) to copy (and modify) your object. ember.copy is indeed deprecated as stated in the ember docs.

```
const original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const copy = { ...original, c: 3 }; // copy => { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
const { a, ...noA } = copy; // noA => { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

[image]

Comment: A spread operator copy is shallow, similar to an Object.assign. It will not copy nested complex objects or arrays (the new copy will reference the same nested objects as the original). OP is looking for a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

You should call Ember's `copy` helper to seamlessly deep copy complex objects.

It accepts two params, `obj` and `deep`.

`obj(Object)` is the object to clone and `deep(Boolean)` If true, a deep copy of the object is made.

eg.

```
obj1 = {name: 'john', surname: {paternal: 'Doe', maternal: 'Cena'}};
obj2 = Ember.copy(obj1, true); // creates deep clone of my obj.
```

[Ember copy helper doc.](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.4/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Finternals/copy)

Comment: 'Copy' is deprecated in the latest versions.

Comment: What do you mean Driezzz? the ember doc link I shared if from ember 3.4 version which is the latest as of now. Please cite proof to your claims.

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/322 Accepted RFC. Also, it says it right there on the website, under 'Function' - 'public deprecated'